# Are there languages that distinguish between inclusive and exclusive "or"?

Tags: semantics, list-of-languages, conjunctions

I would be especially interested in Indo-European languages or other common language families, but failing that, I would be very interested if it exists at all, because it is an important distinction in formal discourse, but can almost always be taken from context in informal speech.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, Basque (in the *batua* dialect) has *ala* "or (exclusive)" and *edo* "or (inclusive)", although *ala* can only be used in questions.

You may also be interested in the WALS maps of languages with an [Inclusive/Exclusive Distinction in Independent Pronouns](http://wals.info/feature/39A) and an [Inclusive/Exclusive Distinction in Verbal Inflection](http://wals.info/feature/40A).

Comment: just curious, are those inclusion/exclusion distinctions that you link related to the or distinction in some way?

Comment: @LouisRhys What do you mean? They're related in that they exhibit an inclusive/exclusive distinction.

Answer (score 13):

In Finnish, *tai* is inclusive, *vai* exclusive, and *eli* is for an equivalence.

E.g.

*Haluaisitko omenia tai päärynöitä?*

"Would you like some apples or pears?

*Haluatko omenan, vai päärynän?*

"Do you want an apple, or a pear?"

*Se on hyvän- ja pahantiedon puun hedelmä, eli omena.*

"It's the fruit of the tree of knowledge of good and bad, or an apple."

Comment: Does the tai/vai distinction appear only in interrogatives?

Comment: Yes, it is restricted to interrogative clauses. This also includes indirect interrogatives, e.g. _Siinä ei ole väliä, onko sinulla omenia vai päärynöitä_ "It isn't important whether you have apples or pears."

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about other languages, but I know that Latin made this distinction:

> In Latin they had several different words for these different 'ors'. AUT was generally exclusive, VEL inclusive, as was -VE on the end of  a word, whilst the 'or' of equivalence was denoted by SIVE or SEU

[Source](http://books.google.com/books?id=7YWC49NVMisC&lpg=PA95&pg=PA95#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Do you know some examples to illustrate the usage? It would be great

Comment: I'm afraid I can't entirely support this. *Aut* is usually a more emphatic word than the others (which, incidentally, are related both etymologically and semantically). Because exclusive *or* is more often used in emphatic sentences, there is perhaps a greater chance that *aut* will be exclusive than *vel* etc.; but the correlation is not very strong, and certainly not reliable. Especially not with negations: *numquam videbam Romam aut Athenas*: "I have never seen Rome or Athens". See *[The Myth of Vel and Aut‎](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/disjunction/#MytVelAut)* from the SEP.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for enlightening me!

Comment: @Cerberus That article no longer supports your comment. Do you have anything up to date on that? (Disjunction in negative clauses also act differently from those in positive clauses.)

Comment: @cmw: Err I could have raised a child since that post...I do not remember anything about this!

Comment: @cmw It does still support the comment, though I don’t know if it went into more detail formerly.  In the section on inclusive/exclusive disjunction in language, it states that _aut_ has been shown to have non-exclusive uses, which is exactly what Cerberus was saying.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "Some" uses is different from a weak correlation, and certainly different from calling it a myth. I was hoping he knew of a quick reference that debunks the old idea. Unfortunately, that article only cites a single example in a negative clause, so it remains a question whether *possum habere hoc aut illud* is/was solely disjunctive. I'll track down Dik and Jennings later to see if they can provide some illumination on that front.

Answer (score 5):

In many European languages we can modify the "or" word by prefixing with "either" to make it exclusive, as in *"You must chose either a or b"* (explicitly not both).

But without modification it's inclusive or exclusive depending on context:
*"Left or right?"* is exclusive since "both" is not "possible" (usually),  while *"Milk or sugar?"* is inclusive because "both" is possible and quite common.

*PS: As a programmer I'd really like the languages to have words for inclusive-or and exclusive-or clearly defined... ;)*

Comment: I suppose the english OR is inclusive. Why do so many people write "and/or"?

Comment: English "or" is ambiguous.  Sometimes it's used to mean OR, sometimes it's used to mean XOR.  For instance, if a menu offers "fries or chips" as part of a combo, I'll probably assume that it means "fries XOR chips" and that I can't ask for both.  So if you're an extra-generous restaurant owner and you *would* be willing to let me order both for the same price, you can write "fries and/or chips," and that makes your generosity unambiguous.

Comment: If English "or" were ambiguous and sometimes meant XOR, then "Alex or Bill or Charles" would have a reading where it means "one or three of (Alex, Bill, Charles)". [The observation is due to Reichenbach and McCawley. See Alonso-Ovalle's thesis (pp.56ff) for a nice exposition: http://alonso-ovalle.net/index.php?page_id=28.]

Comment: @KaivonFintel: Broken link.

Comment: http://people.linguistics.mcgill.ca/~luis.alonso-ovalle/papers/alonso-ovalle-diss.pdf

Comment: >If English "or" were ambiguous and sometimes meant XOR, then "Alex or Bill or Charles" would have a reading where it means "one or three of (Alex, Bill, Charles)"
I mean, "or" between NPs, unlike "and" between NPs, does not have a mereological sense. It doesn't stop it from being either OR or XOR depending on context; "Alex or Bill or Charles came" can indeed mean "came(Alex) XOR came(Bill) XOR came(Charles)" (or, at least, its Russian equivalent can). The question of whether XOR is scalar implicature or a genuine polysemy is unrelated.

Answer (score 3):

I think the closest thing you can get in natural languages the distinction between choice-aimed and simple alternative. Finnish and Basque have already been mentioned, and [here are some more](https://books.google.no/books?id=GNYsbinINo8C&pg=PA286&lpg=PA286&dq=tai+vai+edo+ala+czy+lub&source=bl&ots=y-NzHGKW4O&sig=zxdsce5RvXEqh0bPTKajVEOZ-MI&hl=no&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8iZ7p9-bPAhUmKpoKHVDwBnoQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=tai%20vai%20edo%20ala%20czy%20lub%20albo%20ci%20abo%20apo%20ose%20cy%20abo%20tu%20an%20ja%20wa-ja%20ahi&f=false):

> There are, however, 9 European languages that do not have any general marker for alternative, but show two distinct connectives for choice-aimed alternative and simple alternative relations. These languages are Polish (choice-aimed: *czy*, simple: *lub/albo*), Finnish (choice-aimed: *vai*, simple: *tai*), Belorussian (choice-aimed: *ci*, simple: *abo*), Albanian (choice-aimed: *apo*, simple: *ose*), Basque (choice-aimed: *ala*, simple: *edo*), Ukrainian (choice-aimed: *čy*, simple: *abo*), Georgian (choice-aimed: *tu*, simple: *an*), Lezgian (choice-based: *tax̂ajt'a*, simple: *ja/wa-ja*), Dargi (choice-aimed: *aħi*, simple: *ya-ra*).

This distinction is also present in Mandarin Chinese: choice-aimed alternatives use 還是 *háishì* and simple alternatives use 或者 *huòzhě*.

Note that Polish, Belorussian, Ukrainian and Albanian are all Indo-European, just like you wanted.

Comment: Albanian apo is used exclusively in questions,  ose exclusively in statements/suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Just to coin one more way to express inclusive OR versus exclusive OR.

In Ukrainian, we use **"or X, or Y"** construct to denote exclusivity:

> дай мені яблуко **або** помаранч — "give me an apple or an orange", inclusive;
>   дай мені **або** яблуко, **або** помаранч — "give me either an apple or an orange", exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

In Arabic (classical) ʼam is exclusive, ʼaw is (generally) inclusive.

Comment: Yes! And the distinction is also _technically_ present for interrogative sentences in Modern Standard Arabic, although the average writer today will more often than not be found using ’aw for all purposes, introducing the same ambiguity as with "or" in English.

Answer (score 2):

In Azerbaijani language there are separate connectives for both inclusive and exclusive ors.

**VƏ YA** — inclusive or

**YA DA** — exclusive or

Qapını ört **ya da** bağla — Close or open the door (exclusive sense)

Çantalarınızı **və ya** zənbillırinizi masanın üzərinə qoyun — Put your bags or packages on the table (inclusive sense)

But in non-formal speech "ya da" is used more frequently. And the interesting fact is that inclusive or "və ya" is literally translated as "and or" (which is true including third case, when A and B are both true).

Answer (score 1):

Let us understand the structure of XOR through boolean logic.

A XOR B is (A OR B) AND NOT (A AND B )

Assuming that inclusive OR appears in languages first... XOR could be obtained by applying a further condition to the OzR clause as is done by AND above...

This condition is imposed by
.   Either .in English.
.   'Ya'   . in Hindi interestingly inclusive OR is also Ya in Hindi.

This is derived from Sanskrit  'Va'...  and as per Sanskrit grammer a repetition of this word suggests exclusion ([Learn Sanskrit Online: "And," "Or," and "Not"](http://www.learnsanskrit.org/start/uninflected/andornot)).

So the basic point is that the truth table for XOR can be realized by filtering out the truth table for OR and interestingly most languages make use of this mechanism instead of having a separate XOR operator (word).